# Chrome sometimes downloads html instead showing it

Tags: apache, symfony, google-chrome, windows-10, vpn

I have an Apache server running a website with a symfony 2 login form, two weeks ago some of the users got their computers updated to windows 10, since then, sometimes when they click the login button Chrome downloads this file called "login" i attached instead showing it:

```
0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2016 14:41:00 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.22
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Debug-Token: 7216b3
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

794
‹      ´Y{oÛ8ÿÛù\]‹Ú@$YNÓ¼ä²n»W`swhZÜE!ÐÒØbB‘*I9I/ýP‡ûûÅnHJ~dSl³ˆƒÆó›g8ÃiúS!ss[)MÅOwRûE8óq : ºÎóò«q`TÁé!i   ´8Ýé¥Jò’*
f4f$¶+†§ï&oÈ+@Ñ4öS• Œƒt®Xm˜É¥0 (¸·‹6¦”jsÁ¿§4¦áKÃãàßáÇ³p"«š6å°FòîÍ8žü:rŸ ?…á'6#Üà$9úŒS½ÔËD´ÊÇE?Žck–}]²*šK9çË¢\V±^ˆ
#®ü–èR§iìþ'›}Cy~ä\NrQCÎf,'ç¨†&nÇºÚ×µTfM‹kV˜r\À‚åºÁ.a‚Fy¨sÊaœì’ŠÞ°ª©º    «(q¼[½ìqãiÂ‰/é‚úYkóÞ‚*2UòZƒêõzc”cÁæÔH58u6GN6·½‡9ÜàÎ¸&
%Yq÷3§ùÕÏ ÔíÝ»7^Ó»¿Ë+FïØ?û´¸+¥€;YîþQ£[ó>n¹Cƒ¸ÃfÚÓYf”k°lÖoyF5yÙ_—`0 ÿÁ=½%’Zµ”=Zo(û¯L£Aõ.iì’Y#rë{}$'èÃX²1ý]öãû_§Tí’áà„|Ûõr\GEVÛúÇ¾wÍD!¯#4©äüƒìwOómÇÿº]^K.íù1±v‚“Î§í]µ·kTHq[É·l¬ËDEë/
hCkv·¸ùmuiŠçÞ4ÓQ1œ
þ|49˜?ß{-÷Ã£fDËk„éuèV36oÙ´?© Ø
>¢çTÐ9(9®†ç´^
^;\ùAJ®ñÏ3f]­¼å (Ì:6ëÔïŒž8Á‚Ïk²ÎÅ­E††õbÚÅgNôìUÀµ!6¹¸ðå pSÊ™¸"¥‚Ù8ˆi]gDQ]Öq®u\L‹W‡Ù”jÈ’§‚õ(qc|hs‹ìKTÂ_?
L+ú•5U6Ú6§·è³ÙÞ WtÙË-À_¢÷ªÛ°aÙþÐÏ†»Ì^mMð¨j¸a€ÙÀdÛ´OhðbªY~*ÄËLŠìp§í4eGÛ³ØÃê,nAM•É’$&!ÞˆŒKýÈ@Þù#NÃdïÕèððOsXÞMo1«âÕë3¾«c[O……ŽÉCìŽ™Ux5Æ7¡ŸkÅ›y”?ÚRf…‚¢slòÒ…µÂŠ¥ª¥†"XÓocST‹yðÍ¾‚£›ƒÑwQC·ì°'e‹ž$/oð÷ûøí†‡ÖÊ$þ«‰Omuå~6Ê»S¾Ôñè°íÑ.ô’è(â1_¶§L¨›Ö’Ï#Ñ1°-ƒ¦…­1`É¡ÀÜ°5üßÝL/·Ãkã²Ýß\b¡
sÆvðÝõwðÔà•¬°6Ãç€)CûrÓ˜¶ÃÂöW¬ß1E<1ƒ‚x+Vö6=<1x—Ø’-rÔ–`É–âQ¬L·Çè÷\ª©¼É’'^Ÿ—÷mÖÔ•”¦ôo£§¿S—ŒF¡{Y±¯Ô>ÒB¯"Ö˜O~8KŽ{¡{rcÂ
Ñ’M%ôÓß¸Kf/C+6Ãî!ªŸþÒ]²Ûu3ÅàoôŸºuî5´¼ÛGg<“úR+Œ &æVû'>óïµR~óž>-ê_Ñ!ø”æWcä½÷øø2}M
Ý`âÊ±ÇÈ>Å‡˜S¸±e‹ÁGªæÎï,ón(UT1±©+8„SÛ€J°ˆ½Š’(ÙÛÐÑæ÷¸­±DÔ1l°øQ›¡¨øº/¤ŠWy½æÍœ  Ôa™ßãõ°Š¬ @ß;´®cñH1|º‰»tsõGšY;«6MŽX &îŠ×lÑ÷Ý¢gýáµÄ›ïÅÀ–ò}×ÅÁ“d–ðøjŒg/ví<‡™9&ýg}ßåD®‡`!¹åüë_~uµ‘õq   l^šïRÿ­]FrÛ:²]¤o¨Ô³~!óÆZg) Åm½‡å”ê(°%tÿwÚ#î{À(–…ýX94uûvo:•Åíi/-Ø‚°bt$çTc©ž·`®•˜Î0›êD»–Ž0sMå€T`J‰hhtßƒì¥õ&`;Ëªyë'î9¤-ŒôU?åfØ^s÷–KãzYí[q[<tVmðòA)©s©„­\9G'´6ËXŒèc2Œ : ºû¬¦b
Ç>=Hû21“Kú—ÝÄ:Ë ©¨B]CeÏò˜´€h_ëp’b~:A»ÈµÝ-ï·ÿ     wúe¯ª²T«îz[)§SàÍ‚iP¶wœ~Ô
UL§±[>M§*^R0Q7ë‘¸ó\·íçl5ÑêíÎQdAyc{ó÷mþ°d5\K…¾1‘ïE
¿ý—þ±tK2'ájÔJ¸šxHÂ
¹º6àCÎåØNcðL—žù‰î
n³ 3N|¬%©Jc¿¾¤÷lÒØú½}çúÓÂèqac£ÈýËÿ  ÿÿ
a
 °•Tüq  
0
```

Only computers using google Chrome that have been updated to windows 10 have this issue. Other computers using Chrome or using Internet Explorer from the same computer works fine.
I have tried to change the response headers of the Content-Type to text/html using the ModHeader extension but the Chrome shows the same content of the file without interpreting it.
I have tried with older versions of Chrome with the same result.
Also I disabled the Apache compression but still sometimes Chrome downloads the page.
The user have disabled the antivirus but the issue keeps the same.
Browsing a similar version of the application hosted in another server works fine.

I don't know if the issue is related to the clients or the server.

**Edit:**
It looks like the computers have FortiNet installed and it could be breaking the network packages.